# Play single mp3 through specific Pipewire device via shell command

Tags: linux, audio, shell, pipewire

I'm trying to figure out a way to play a single mp3 file through a specific Pipewire output device via a shell command.

Only this one file should be played through that device. I don't want to change the default device. I just need a command that specifies the device and then plays this single file through that device, like so:

```
somecommand -o "bluez_output.25_4E_4A_C7_43_C4.1" "foo.mp3"
```

The device name in this example is the device's `node.name` grabbed from `pw-cli list-objects`.

I use pipewire-pulse, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pipewire-pulse you can act as if you were using PulseAudio. `paplay` is a basic command to play audio on a PulseAudio sound server:

```
paplay -d "bluez_output.25_4E_4A_C7_43_C4.1" "foo.mp3"
```

In my Kubuntu 23.04 it works well with mp3 files. `node.name`s from `pw-cli list-objects` agree with `pactl list sinks`. I notice that in Bash or in Zsh `paplay -d` <kbd>tab</kbd> gives me quite sane autocompletion.

Comment: Thank you, this works. My follow-up problem is that this doesn't work as root. I'm trying to run this from a systemd service, which has root environment variables. I noticed that pipewire tools work as root, but pulse tools do not. Unfortunately, `su username` doesn't restore variables required by pulse, so it doesn't help. Hence a pipewire-native equivalent of `paplay` would still be quite useful in my use case. But your answer still solves the problem as described in my question.

Comment: Wait, I can just use a user service, duh. At least in my case that works fine.